# Could BEQ command make an overflow?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, cpu-architecture, integer-arithmetic

As we all know, BEQ defined as folllows:
`if($x == $y) PC = PC + 4 + 4*(offset) else PC = PC+4`.

We also know that the ALU substract using 2-complement method. With that in mind:

> Is it possible that BEQ cause an overflow?

Well, I've said yes; Let's take for example: `$x = 01...1$` and `$y = 10...01` (minus 1 in decimal). Then of course the result is invalid and there is an overflow.

Am I right, or is there something I'm missing in this question?

Comment: Define _"make an overflow"_. Are you talking about an `IntegerOverflow` exception being generated? If not, I don't see how it matters, since `BEQ` only cares about whether the difference between `x` and `y` is zero.

Comment: Your don't seem to understand 2's-complement arithmetic. `-1` is `0xF...F` in hexadecimal, or `0b1...1` in binary. `0b10...01` is `INT_MIN + 1`.

Comment: The operation isn't defined in terms of subtraction, it's defined in terms of an equality comparison. That means the instruction can't overflow because an equality comparison can't overflow. You can't assume it must be implemented internally using the same hardware to perform subtraction. Even if this happens to be true, the implementation must behave as if an equality comparison was performed.

Comment: @RossRidge, we're talking MIPS so the implementation is done with substraction.

Comment: Anyhow, maybe I confused with the 2-complement arithmetic but the question still remains.

Comment: @Michael, I mean `IntegerOverflow` caused by the substraction operation in the ALU

Comment: In that case you can just look it up in _MIPS32 Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32 Instruction Set_. For `BEQ` it says: _"Exceptions: None"_.

Comment: No exceptions, yet if I substract a negative number from a huge number then we get an overflow, aren't we?

Comment: That may be the case, but it's not observable, so I still don't see how it matters.

Comment: Nothing in the MIPS instruction set requires that implementation be done with substation. The instruction set requires that it be implemented **as if** it was done using an equality comparison. You may have been taught the MIPS instruction set using a particular MIPS implementation but you're mistaken in thinking that this implementation is the only one possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer:

No BEQ **cannot** cause an overflow in the MIPS32 ISA.

#### Details:

Based on the comments I'm assuming you are talking about BEQ in the MIPS32 ISA.  Looking at the [MIPS32 Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32 Instruction Set](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/mips_vol2.pdf) shows that BEQ cannot cause any exceptions.

It is true that comparison is typically implemented by subtracting one value from another, and in a MIPS implementation this instruction could be implemented using the same ALU.  So the ALU will generate the signal for an overflow (caused by a carryout from the high-order bit), but if the CPU is executing a BEQ instruction it will ignore the overflow.  Whereas if it's executing a SUB instruction then it will trigger an exception.

For an alternative example you can look at [SPARC V8](http://gaisler.com/doc/sparcv8.pdf).  In SPARC V8:

> The integer arithmetic instructions are generally
>   triadic-register-address instructions which compute a result that is a
>   function of two source operands, and either write the result into the
>   destination register r[rd] or discard it . . .
>   Most of these instructions are available in dual versions; one version
>   sets the integer condition codes (icc) as a side effect; the other
>   version does not affect the condition codes.

In both cases the CPU will use the same ALU to compute the arithmetic operation and if an overflow occurs the signal from the ALU which indicates this will be set.  But if the instruction is not set to update the condition codes then the CPU won't do anything with that value.

MIPS32 doesn't have a condition code register, but the same principles apply if it uses the same ALU operation for the comparison in BEQ and for SUB it's free to ignore overflow for BEQ, but for SUB the overflow signal would trigger an exception.